# How should I reference the required assemblies into the project solution from another solution

Tags: visual-studio

I have the following solution:

**Solution1**

|---- **Project1**

|---- **Project2**

**Solution2**

|---- **Project3**

|---- **Project4**

Can you please share the multiple ways (Best Practies) to add reference from another solution? In my case, I want to add Project 2 reference in Project 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.dll` of project2 in project 3

Comment: And if any changes mode in Project 2, build it and overwrite it in project 3